# How is it done "Manage this list" on amazon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I'm specifically looking, how is the hover on done? and what did they use? JavaScript? Jquery, DHTML? and does anyone have example?
Now, I'm new to web programming. (but not new to programming, I'm c++ and c# prg).
I'm looking into getting web dev. for personal use. I saw this amazon feature and thought to myself that it would be nice to do something like this (i.e. menu) on my own website and inline editing, but I'm not sure where and how to start. 
I'm looking for resources, books and general examples. I know that I could google, but I'm not sure what to google, I'm not sure what's it called and what to look for.

Thanks guys.

EDIT: Example of it:
http://www.amazon.com/wishlist/ref=topnav_lists
Go to amazon wishlist -> click on any of your wishlists.
Then in the middle of the screen you should see "Manage this list"

Comment: Can you provide a link or describe how to get there? A screenshot perhaps?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a particularly good place to get "resources, books, and general examples."  Once you get started, it's a great place to get answers to specific questions you have while you try and get your pages to work.

Comment: What part of this feature is causing you trouble?

Comment: @ricebowl - I don't know where to start to be honest. I also don't know what did they use, was is it JavaScript? How can I tell?

Comment: Break your question into smaller, specific questions and then put all the answers together to achieve your aim/layout. Sorry, but this is just way too broad to answer as is.

Answer (score 0):

get yourself a firefox browser and install add on firebug.

when you enter the page open firebug(F12)
and there you will be able to follow what is happening on the page in most times

usually you will se something as ajax requests loading pages

after scripts and loads more. I recomend to read up a bit about javascript and html for beginning.

the menu what do you see there is javascript action, or jquery (i did not looked too close)

the problem as david wrote is, you have to be more specific what you want to achieve:)

good luck